# Finding an exponential model for a set of given data

Tags: solution-verification, exponential-function, regression

I have a problem here I am working on that is asking me to "Find an equation of the line through the first and last data points. Then find an exponential model $P(x)$ for the population data. Use natural logs of $y$ coordinates to find the equation of the regression line."

The population data: $(0,10), (1,15), (2,23), (3,35), (4,54)$

I just started by finding the equation of the secant line through the first and last points and got $$y = 11x + 10$$

From here I wasn't exactly sure what to do, after a bit of looking around I looked at a hint to the problem which stated "Fitting a line to the plot of the natural logarithms is equivalent to fitting an exponential function to the original data. Allow $y = \ln (P(x))$, then find a line of best fit.

From this suggestion I equated $$11x + 10 = y = \ln (P(x)) \implies P(x) = e^{(11x + 10)} = e^{11x} + e^{10}$$

However this doesn't seem to be correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would the best fit be the one through the first and last data points?  Don't the other data points matter?  And $e^{A+B}$ *is not* $e^A+e^B$.

Comment: You want to do linear regression on the sample points $(x_i,\ln y_i)$